# Consejos para mejorar script que crea backup de base de datos y poder enviarlo por correo automáticamente

Tags: base-de-datos, linux, bash, email

He creado un script para linux que permite realizar un respaldo de la BD  guardándolo en un archivo comprimido con fecha y hora de elaboración.

Ademas se envía mediante correo automáticamente y me borra los archivos ".bz2" *(que es el formato que use para comprimir el backup)* que tenga una antigüedad mayor de 30 días.

Quiero mejorar el script que me recomienda para ello:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FECHA=($(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S") )# fecha de elaboración
export NAME=RespaldoBD_${FECHA}.backup # nombre del respaldo
export DIR=/home/backup/ #direccion donde se guarda los documentos
USER_DB=admin #usuario de la BD
NAME_DB=nombre # nombre de la BD
USER_GMAIL=@gmail.com #direccion de correo a enviar 
MESSAGE_FILE=backup.mail.message # colocar este archivo en DIR.
```

El `"MESSAGE_FILE=backup.mail.message"` es un  documento tipo txt que contiene un mensaje o una descripción a poner dentro de correo a enviar, este documento se coloca en el mismo lugar donde va estar el backup de la base de datos para que sea mejor.

```
cd $DIR > ${NAME} #se habre direccion donde se guardara el backup
export PGPASSWORD=xxxx #clave de la BD
chmod 777 ${NAME} #se le da permisos al archivo
echo "procesando la copia de la base de datos" #mensaje a ver 

pg_dump -i -h (ip del servidor) -p (puerto) -U $USER_DB -F c -b -v -f ${NAME}  $NAME_DB # comando para crear el backup
echo "backup terminado" #mensaje a ver 
# usamos bzip2 para comprimir el sql
 bzip2 ${NAME}
```

Ahora enviamos el backup por correo usando mutt, el código se mete entro de un `until` para crear un ciclo para que persista hasta enviarlo de forma exitosa.

```
# Enviar correo 
until
mutt -s "Copia de seguridad BD ${NAME_DB}: $(date +"%d-%m-%Y")" ${USER_GMAIL} -a ${NAME}.bz2 < ${DIR}${MESSAGE_FILE} 
do echo "   NO SE ENVIO CORREO REINTENTANDO ... " :; done
echo "SE ENVIO CORREO"
#Elimina archivos mayor a 30 dias
find ${DIR}*.bz2 -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

Posteriormente se muestra un mensaje si no se puede enviar y entra en el ciclo y cuando es enviado muestra otro mensaje.

Por ultimo se tiene el código para eliminar los comprimidos .bz2 que tengan mas de 30 días en la dirección dada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# set vars
FECHA=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H%M%S") # fecha de elaboración
USER_DB="admin" #usuario de la BD
NAME_DB="nombre" # nombre de la BD
USER_GMAIL=@gmail.com #direccion de correo a enviar 
NAME="$NAME_DB-$FECHA.backup" # nombre del respaldo
DIR=/home/sigefirrhh/backup/ #direccion donde se guarda los documentos
MESSAGE_FILE=backup.mail.message # colocar este archivo en DIR.

export_db(){
    cd $DIR > ${NAME} #se habre direccion donde se guardara el backup
    chmod 777 ${NAME} #se le da permisos al archivo

    echo "[+] procesando la copia de la base de datos" #mensaje a ver

    [[ ! -z $1 ]] && export PGPASSWORD=$1 || echo "[-] requiere password!"; exit;
    [[ -z $2 ]] && IP=$1 || IP="locahost";
    [[ -z $3 ]] && PORT=5432 || PORT=$1;
    [[ ! -d DIR ]] && mkdir -p $DIR; # si no existe la carpeta la cree antes de que no marque error!

    pg_dump -i -h $IP -p $PORT -U $USER_DB -F c -b -v -f ${NAME}  $NAME_DB # comando para crear el backup
    echo "[+] backup terminado" #mensaje a ver 
    # usamos bzip2 para comprimir el sql
    bzip2 ${NAME}

     # Enviar correo 
    until
    mutt -s "Copia de seguridad BD ${NAME_DB}: $(date +"%d-%m-%Y")" ${USER_GMAIL} -a ${NAME}.bz2 < ${DIR}${MESSAGE_FILE} 
    do echo "[-]  NO SE ENVIO CORREO REINTENTANDO ... " :; done
    echo "SE ENVIO CORREO"
    #Elimina archivos mayor a 30 dias
    find ${DIR}*.bz2 -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
}

# lee el password:
read -sp 'Password: ' PASS
export_db $PASS $1 $2

# como utilizar
#./dbbackup  ip port

# 1. password_db(requerido)
# 2. ip(optional default:localhost)
# 3. port(opcional default:5432) 

#nunca almacenas las contrase;as en texto plano
#PGPASSWORD=xxxx
```